Is endorsing a first lady to be president sign of effectively nepotic-like political dynasty?
This question was formed because of Hillary Clinton and Michelle Obama recurringly being seen as viable Presidential Candidates.
Being first lady is a great position politically to know what it takes to do the President's job but beyond that, wouldn't the public see this definitively as a kind of same deck leadership taking place if these spouses were to incur charge of the US. We already saw a brush with dynasty like in the case of the Bush father-son. In India, for a time dominant leadership was with the Nehru family.
Imagine a future where Melania Trump is in the race, Hunter Biden or even Don Jr. It can be reasoned that certain groups experience a retention in power and connection when the candidate pool that one can choose from is made connected like this.
Is it in the spirit of the constitution to allow the pool of political celebrities like first ladies and direct relatives to remain in the political arena hindering fresh new individuals from taking charge, that could potentially do a better job at representing, understanding and responding to the growing needs of the newer generation in concern now.
Has one ever claimed such running is undemocratic somehow to the extent it be barred? How?
I assume, in asking this question, a position that political dynasties are against the spirit of true democracy and policy should be adopted to curb recycling a deep state with allowed change only being a superficial one.

Are you really suggesting that someone isn't qualified to be president because they also used to be the first lady?

I've intentionally worded this question NOT to indicate such a bias. Please do not read between lines. However, I definitively wish a determinism to whether such endorsement is nepotism or completely democratic process. Thank you in advance.

follow-up: is it considered nepotism if a large part of Trump's family had charges in his administration?

I am sorry but even the idea is outrageous if you take a look at Hillary Clinton's resume which includes 8 years as a senator and 4 years as the secretary of state. In her case it should be clear that her being seen as fit for being president has nothing to do with her being a first lady. As far as your imagined future has there been any indication that Melania Trump wants to run for President? Michelle Obama has made it clear that she doesn't.

Can you clarify where you see the nepotism? A former presidential spouse running for president would have to jump though all the hoops as everyone else.

Your title asks if it can a 'sign of nepotism' to endorse a first lady , and the body asks 'is it constitutional' to allow someone like a first lady to 'remain in the political arena'. What is your actual question? The title question seems opinion-based, and the body question doesn't make much sense since there have been several presidents who were children/relatives of previous presidents.

There seem to be four questions and two of them are matters of opinion; one is verging on opinion but could be answered with a poll; the other is a question of what the constitution says.

Fun fact re: nepotism from Twitter: this is the first election since 1976 where a Bush, a Biden or a Clinton is not running on a ticket. But at least there's a Kennedy running as a third-party candidate :-)

Point of interest: Melania is not a natural born US citizen, and so is ineligible for the presidency.

Something something old people, something something survivorship bias, something something too much to address. Answers claim this loose nepotism where the public is the boss is not unconstitutional. It is populist and process does not seem democratic fit. Offended by interpretation that this is in bad faith. Best question I formulated this year.

Since this post has died, let me address the first highly voted comment again, I didn't intend this in the spirit that they were unqualified to get through the process. My thoughts was along the lines that these are essentially the same people and essentially the same powers extending term. No one addressed that but they want to see it as democratic, which in technicality it could be but in spirit, loses me.

@MisterGeeky You seem to keep on using words that don’t mean what you think they do. It’s democratic if The People get to vote on it. Whom a president endorsed isn’t democratic regardless of the endorsed person, and which candidate the people vote for is democratic regardless of the endorsed person. All the things you implicitly tack on to this, such as making room for the next generation, are nice and maybe sensible but not inherently democratic or undemocratic (constitutional or unconstitutional (…)).

You are right. I did not have the word for what it is.

@TedWrigley: IIRC people expect Don Jr. to run at some point, not Melania. https://youtu.be/u8yL3I_6Oco?t=497

"I did not have the word for what it is". I think the word you're looking for is "political dynasty". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_family#:~:text=A%20political%20family%20(also%20referred,multiple%20siblings%20may%20be%20involved.

It seems there are some countries like the Philipines that have some rules/limits on these https://news.abs-cbn.com/news/02/06/23/carlos-wants-to-scrap-term-limits-lift-ban-on-dynasties but I'm not terribily familiar with that situation. Now that you know the term, perhaps you can ask a better Q.

FYI: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/88465/does-the-anti-dynasty-provision-of-the-philippines-have-parallels-in-other-cou

@timetakesitstoll: Don Jr may throw his hat in the ring, sure, but I can't see it being a successful bid. Junior doesn't command the same appeal in the MAGA base that senior does, mainly because senior has managed to convince people he's a self-made man, while junior has a distinct air of nepo-baby. I suspect junior could only achieve the presidency if senior were to take office and corrupt the electoral system that he could pass the presidency on to junior without challenge.

Hi, thank you to everyone still engaging in this question, I have updated it slightly while still retaining my original voice and intent. I know there is definitely better questions hidden in the concept we have formed here together and more insights into moralistic governance and leadership, however I need to express that I am not attacking monarchy and the power of familial rule, I want to extend this question even to things as abstract as interest groups and corporate monopolies because I feel it is foundationally important it be asked and it stay in public awareness and conciousness.

There is still a big problem with this question as it is suggesting that only a single person has a say in who is the next president with their endorsement. There are still millions of people who have a say in the nomination as well as the person having very well established credentials for the job. This isn't a simple case of someone with no qualifications becoming president because their husband endorsed them.


Can one claim such running is undemocratic somehow to the extent it be barred?

What's undemocratic about 'wife of a president' running for office?
She would need to follow the same process as any other candidate and the electorate will decide whether or not to vote for her.
While endorsing the first lady may give her substantial support from the president's supporters, this does not constitute a violation of democratic principles.

Pool of power acclimation does not shift drastically to give air to unrepresented and stagnating people groups when they are represented by essentially a single deck of players. Stirring the pot is required to cook evenly, lest the unreported get burnt.

@MisterGeeky maybe you want to sound deep, but it does not seem that you are saying anything at all other than rehashing some memes. Also, are you on a diet? All of you analogies are related to food...

Yes Juan, I also craved to sate that hunger with knowledge that the system in play will  favor us with a fresh young face more capable to lead and affect ground level undesirables like unplanned hunger and what have you... I did not hear anything today to the tune of adding any fire to that desire. Also, this was really the best answer. A simple no - "your position is wrong". However can expand why this does not violate democratic principles. It just did not spiritually sit right. Hence, the trying to be deep

Nepotism generally means hiring relatives for significant positions. For example, when former president Trump placed his children and their spouses in key administration positions, that was clearly nepotism. However, elected offices are not 'given' to people by the current president; they are won through an election process in which every candidate needs to secure votes for themselves. No one can gain an elected office merely because a powerful relative or friend wills it to be so, so nepotism in its proper sense can't happen.

Are you sure if I put a cake infront of you, you won't go to the ballot poll and choose it over the salad? The public will is coerced by the opportunity to cling onto sameness.

@MisterGeeky The analogy makes no sense. If you put a salad and a cake in front of me, perhaps (probably) I will chose the food even if it is not the best option for me. But you are not coercing me to take the bad option. To be frank, calling it coercion seems quite a dishonest argument.

There is a fridge you do not know about. There is a store you are not party to. There are movers and shakers executing a grand circus and all you can do is play Hamlet with the cake, to eat cake or not to eat cake - all the while it didn't need to be on the table. Honestly, what's the point in the choice if the decision consequence is already planned - the choice made for you and you choose to choose it. That's very much coercion.

@MisterGeeky: There's clearly a 'party' problem here with both the Repubs and the Dems. The parties (to a large extent) dictate who we can choose for the nominee, and they are not always entirely respectful of the Public.  Parties are a problem.  I doubt Trump would be the 2024 Repub nominee except that he took very unsubtle actions to wrest control of party mechanisms and force them to choose him.  But within the Dems, Harris has popular support (something like 80% of voters approve of her), and it's likely she would have been the nominee  even if Biden had dropped out earlier.

@MisterGeeky: if you want to complain about party politics (which I encourage you to do) don't pretend only one party has a problem. The dems may have to scramble a bit to straighten things out, but what they are doing in 2024 (unlike what they did in 2016) is about as kosher as it can be. But if you just want to go down the rabbit-hole and eat all the cakes that say "Eat Me", there's not much else for me to say. Try not to sit on any walls…

You make a good point but we digress. Your answer notes what the proper sense of nepotism is, I try to highlight the representation and connected powers issue with this question. It does not matter if those in power favor those in thei connected group or not if effecively we make the decision to go with a result the same as if nepotism or fsvoritism had occured. What the pedantic focus on what exactly is said over the spirit of what is said does is darken the point going unaddressed which is what is in effect happening when same deck personalities and their connections lengthen tenure.

@MisterGeeky: I understand your point, but I disagree with your framing. The problem of nepotism isn't merely that a favored person gets hired; it's that a favored person gets hired over more qualified and able people. Nepotism is hiring a nephew who can't draw stick figures to be chief architect for your firm. You'd have to argue that Harris was picked over more competent, able, and popular candidates. Given Harris' record and polling numbers, that's a really difficult argument to make (at least without resorting to other 'isms', like racism and sexism).

@MisterGeeky: Odd and difficult as it may seem, sometimes the favored person actually is the best person for the job. The right thing to do then is to accept the accusations of nepotism and allow her to prove herself. Calling this nepotism is morally equivalent to suggesting she's a DEI hire, and while I know that's all the rage in conservative circles at the moment, it's a difficult assertion to make stick.

John Adams was one of the Founding Fathers of America, organised the committee that wrote the the US Constitution, and went on to serve as the 2nd President between 1797 and 1801. His son, John Quincy Adams, later served as the 6th President from 1825 to 1829. If we're going with the definition that relatives of former presidents being nominated is a sign of nepotism, then those signs have been around since the very beginning, and are clearly constitutional. I fail to see how a former First Lady being endorsed for presidency is any more egregious than any of the historical examples.
As for whether nepotism is undemocratic, I'll note that it's not enough by itself to get someone into the White House. Voters have two opportunities to reject candidates they believe have benefitted from nepotism: once in the primaries (where Jeb Bush lost in 2016), and once in the main election (where Hillary Clinton already lost once before, also in 2016).

Just because a father was elected as the 2nd president and the son was elected as the 6th president doesn't mean that it is nepotism and it doesn't matter if the father is still alive. In the end 13 of of the 24 state congressional delegations selected him for president in a contested election.

Going by OP's definition of "nepotism" here, I'll edit to make that clearer.

Jeb Bush being both a son of and a brother of a previous president.

Thank you for that clarification, that makes much more sense.

The process is not at fault, noted. One is not inclined to improve upon representation policy because of historic precedence inorder to conserve traditions of familiarity.


This question was formed because of Hillary Clinton and Michelle Obama being seen as viable Presidential Candidates.

This is not a hypothetical situation. Hillary Clinton already ran for Democratic presidential candidate in 2008 and ran for president in 2016.
This was not unconstitutional or undemocratic back then and is not either today.
If a former president endorses their spouse despite them not being a suitable candidate, this would be nepotism but of minor effect - a candidate still has to go through all the hoops of actually getting elected.

Proof by historic example. Not a single answer here to address any issue this causes. It's fair because it happened and it will keep happening and there's nothing OP or anyone irked can do about it.
