Does the "anti-dynasty" provision of the Philippines have parallels in other countries?
I've read an article about a proposed "anti-dynasty" bill in the Philippines:

Under SB 2730, [Senator] Padilla proposed that no spouse or person related within the fourth degree of consanguinity or affinity, whether legitimate or illegitimate, full or half blood, to an incumbent elective official seeking re-election, “shall be allowed to hold or run for any elective office in the same city and/or province, or any party list in the same election."
If the constituency of the incumbent elective official is national in character, such relatives shall be disqualified from running only within the same province where the former is domiciled or in any, including the same, national position.
"(N)o person who has a political dynasty relationship to the incumbent shall immediately succeed to the position of the latter," the bill said.
The bill requires any person running for any elective public office to file a sworn statement with the Commission on Elections (Comelec) that he or she does not have a political dynasty relationship with any incumbent public official running for an elective public office in the same city and/or province other than the position earlier mentioned.
A petition to disqualify a candidate on grounds of political dynasty may be filed before the Comelec, which will conduct summary proceedings.

N.B. the Senator who proposed this bill also claims it's "a measure seeking to finally fulfill the 1987 Constitution's mandate to prohibit political dynasties." Wikipedia fills in what the Constitution itself says on the matter:

The 1987 Constitution of the Philippines states in Article II Section 26: "The State shall guarantee equal access to opportunities for public service, and prohibit political dynasties as may be defined by law."

Does this kind of prohibition an equivalent in other countries?

This isn't your personal blog, you don't need to include all the irrelevant stuff at the start of your question. Just briefly summarise the Philippines' rule as best you can and ask about other countries.

@StuartF idk. some short context can often clarify a question.


Does the "anti-dynasty" provision of the Philippines have parallels in
other countries?

No. It does not.
While it is always challenging to prove a negative, an academic journal article on political dynasties in India, by Siddharth Eapen George & Dominic Ponattu in 2018, notes that:

Political dynasties are present in over 144 countries around the world
and are a frequent topic of public discussion.

The Philippines, however, with its 1987 constitutional provision prohibiting political dynasties and efforts to pass implementing legislation that has been in progress on and off then, appears to be the only country with a constitutional prohibition on them (despite and because of the fact that they are pervasive in the Philippines).
It is a particularly hot legal issue in Indonesia where the issue has played out in conflict of interest claims involving the Indonesian Supreme Court and its dynastic families. Indonesia passed a limited ban in March of 2015 that was struck down by a conflicted Indonesian Supreme Court, which had family members of leading politicians on it, as unconstitutional:

the Indonesian parliament passed a law that prohibits anyone
with one degree of separation from an incumbent, by blood or marriage,
from running for one of the country’s more than five hundred mayoral,
district-head, and provincial-governor seats until at least one
five-year term has passed.

Other legal restrictions on running for office that impaired dynasty formation (like minimum age limits and bans on felons running for public office) were also struck down by the same court.
None of the political science and economics literature on political dynasties mention any anti-dynastic legal provisions in any country other than the Philippines or Indonesia.
Political dynasties have been a central feature, at least some of the time, in the politics of most countries in East Asia, Southeast Asia, and South Asia (see the references at the link as well). It is also common in the Middle East.
This isn't a new issue in democratic politics and there is even a name for it "dynastic democracy" (see also here).
For example, political dynasties were pervasive in European city-states that were nominally democratic in the Middle Ages and into the early modern period. And, of course, it is hard to argue against dynastic electoral politics in countries that are already constitutional monarchies with the dynastic principle burned into their head of state selection system.

Do you want to add in that political dinasties also exist in the US (Kennedy, Bush, Clinton)? I can't think of a prominent example in a mayor EU country but that could just be a lack of knowledge.

@EikePierstorff Clintons might become dynasty, created by upstart Bill. However political dynasties are commonplace in the US - Bushes and Kennedies are the most known because they had multiple members in the top tier, but if we take into account state senators, mayors and other elected officials, then the picture is grim. Among the well-knowns, note also Bidens and Romneys.

@quarague Trudeau (father and son), Churchills (who were the junior branch of the Marlborough family and thus not entitled to the Lordship - English lords are by definition political families.)

@quarague Ian Paisley and his son (UK), Willem Drees and his son (Netherlands), Benito Mussolini and his granddaughter (Italy).  There are many more.

Ironically, this came as a result of the massive corruption of Ferdinand Marcos and then they elect the same crime family again.

@quarague I one considers the top two layers in a country's political system, there are probably more examples, e.g. for Germany "Ernst Carl Julius Albrecht ... served as Minister President of the state of Lower Saxony from 1976 to 1990. He was the father of the politician Ursula von der Leyen, the President of the European Commission."

@quarague Ernst von Weizsäcker Richard von Weizsäcker and Ernst Ulrich von Weizsäcker. Also, the number of members of the Bismarck family that held political offices goes into two digits.
